# Large amount of http connections from self

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, memcached

I have a relatively high traffic linux/apache webserver running Wordpress (oh the headaches). I think our developer configured the memcache settings incorrectly because when I run this command to look at all incoming httpd connections.

```
sudo netstat -anp |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

I get:

```
  1 68.106.x.x
  1 74.125.x.x
  1 74.125.x.x
  1 74.125.x.x
  1 74.125.x.x
 15 0.0.0.0
 70 173.0.x.x
194 127.0.0.1
```

...I see that I have 194 connections from 127.0.0.1, and VERY few from actual public IP's. looking at netstat further I can see those are going to port 11211 (memcache). Even if I restart httpd, it only takes a few seconds for the open memcached connections from 127.0.0.1 to skyrocket up again and almost immediately we are pushing our max httpd process limit (currently MaxClients = 105).

Here are the details for those connections:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:26210             127.0.0.1:11211             ESTABLISHED -
```

cat /etc/sysconfig/memcached

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="1024"
CACHESIZE="64"
OPTIONS=""
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: The question is quite obvious, the thing that's missing is the actual configuration

Comment: What is the reason for the high connections from 127.0.0.1 with memcache and why are they immediately popping up? Would you like httpd.conf or would you like the memcache configuration? I'll post the memcache configuration for you.

Comment: I've added it to my original post.

Comment: Call `netstat` with `-t` and you’ll see the process, if you’re allowed to.

Comment: I've done that, it shows those connections are associated to memcache. However, I did disable keep-alive (was set to 3 seconds) in apache and it seems to have improved. The problem before was that all 105 processes (which is MaxClients) were running, yet we were still able to connect to the site. I'm curious if memcache is taking up those free httpd processes and using them until customers come to the site?